# I can't create the React project using npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I use `npx create-react-app myapp` rule, but it get stuck in a image(it just runs there), and my node_modules file isn't completed.
My npm and node version is lastest ver.

I have run `npm install -g create-react-app` to setup environment and `npm cache clean --force` to clean cache of npm but it still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: try reinstall and you could be waiting a minute for the process fulfilling. I think the images which you upload don't error, it's doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: It could be a network issue, you can delete the folder and try again.

Comment: if none else, you could try using yarn: `yarn create react-app`

Comment: I waited 3 hours for it, but the process only run there. Although I tried reinstall node and yarn,  everything has not changed...

Comment: `yarn create react-app` has the same result

Comment: To be sure, are you running `Node` >= v8.10 and `npm` >= v5.6? Also, don't install `create-react-app`, just run it using `npx`.

Comment: I attempted to run everything commands following instructions of React home page, `npx create-react-app newapp` ...

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether cmd.exe is in a suspended state in the Task manager -> CPU section ->  open resource monitor. If it is suspended there then resume it.

Check below URL to find the  image to find the resource monitor

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6tzL.jpg)